# Java creating a type of form with GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to make a Pythagoras theorem calculator. Right now, I am trying to make a form using `GridLayout`. You enter the values of side A, B or C and check the radio button on the side that is missing. However, my `JTextField` is too big, I'd like it to go horizontal with the label. I do not want to use any other lyout manager.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TriangleCalculator extends JFrame{

    private JLabel sideALabel, sideBLabel, sideCLabel, triangleImage;
    private JTextField sideAInput,sideBInput, sideCInput;
    private JRadioButton sideAOption, sideBOption, sideCOption;
    private JButton calculateButton, clearButton;
    private JPanel buttonPane, mainPanel;

    public TriangleCalculator(){
        super("TriangleCalculator");
        addComponents();
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void addComponents()
    {
        sideALabel = new JLabel("Enter the value of side A: ");
        sideBLabel = new JLabel("Enter the value of side B: ");
        sideCLabel = new JLabel("Enter the value of side C: ");

        sideAInput = new JTextField();
        sideBInput = new JTextField();
        sideCInput = new JTextField();

        sideAOption = new JRadioButton();
        sideBOption = new JRadioButton();
        sideCOption = new JRadioButton();

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

        buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainPanel.add(sideALabel);
        mainPanel.add(sideAInput);
        /*mainPanel.add(sideAOption);*/

        buttonPane.add(clearButton);
        buttonPane.add(calculateButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not want to use any other lyout manager.

That's not the way layout management works. Each layout manager has its rules. If one layout manager doesn't do what you want, then you need to use a different layout manager or nest panels containing different layout managers to achieve your effect.

You could use a `GridBagLayout`. It will support columns of different sizes. However, when you create the text fields you will need to use:

```
sideAInput = new JTextField(10);
```

so the layout manager knows how big to create the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I have made a form with gridLayout and it works perfectly as well as being resizable